# Can we opt for fast track service after the refusal?

Tags: visas, uk

Last Saturday, I got a refusal from BHC due to lack of funds and my reasons to come back to India. I am planning to visit my family who are settled in the UK. I am married and planning to visit my family along with my husband. My father is sponsoring our whole trip. But we got a refusal as we didn't show much funds in our account. We thought that if my father is sponsoring, we should show his documents only. But now I have applied again with a fast track service. Will BHC will consider it under the fast track process? This time I have cleared all their doubts which they mentioned in the refusal letter.

Comment: I know it's been long but did you get the visa? what was the final out come

Answer (score 11):

If you have had a prior refusal, the fast-track (or premium) service is not something you can qualify for.  They need extra time to pull up your transcripts and match your current circumstances to your previous circumstances.

If you paid for fast-track, they will generally keep the money and put your application in the normal queue.

On the VFS India site...

> If you have been refused a visa for any one of these countries or
>   overstayed your visa to the UK or been removed or otherwise been
>   required to leave the UK, the processing of your application is likely
>   to take longer than the processing times set out below, and is
>   unsuitable for the priority process.

Source [UK Visa Information - India](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/india/user_pay_services.html#3)

**Adding...**

The way to restore eligibility for fast-track service following a refusal is generally to get a visa to the USA, but this is not always the case. These policies are set locally.