# UK consulate in Chennai made a mistake and refused my visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals

I applied at the UK consulate in Chennai, India, for a  visa for me, my spouse and our two children.

I stated that my yearly income was 2,000,000 and my total yearly income including other sources of income was 4,000,000. However, they refused my visa, saying that my monthly income was 200,000 INR and the other income was 400,000 INR. It looks like they misread the amounts.

Should I reapply? I called the UK customer care center (which charges £1.37 per minute) and had them send an enquiry to the Chennai consulate, but it will take 15 working days to get a reply.

I have to travel 10 days from today, as two other families are traveling with us. We have made our booking and even have paid for flights.

Is there any way to contact the UK consulate directly, or should I just reapply using the priority process which gets the decision in 5 days? The only contact source is though VFS, which is a third party.

[image][image]

Comment: If you monthly income was 20,00,000, how can your early income be 40,00,000?

Comment: I wonder if part of the problem is a confusion between [English and Indian-style digit grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping).

Comment: `But I have to travel within 10 days from today as the rest of the 2 familys are traveling` The UK embassy doesn't care about that. That's why they ask you apply way ahead of time, like two months.

Comment: `Or should I just reapply in fast process which gets the result in 5 days ?` That won't work. [Once you have had a previous application refusal, fast tracking no longer works](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57809/can-we-opt-for-fast-track-service-after-the-refusal). They will handle your application just like a regular one.

Comment: It might help if you uploaded a copy of your refusal notice, with any personal information blacked out.

Comment: Sorry , yearly income 20,00,000 with other source of income total 40,00,000 a year.

Comment: Did you consider simply applying again using the international number grouping in your application? like 2,000,000 and then write the amount (2 million INR) next to it just to clear the confusion? of course with submitting the required bank statements/salary slips...

Comment: The zealot, "That won't work. Once you have had a previous application refusal, fast tracking no longer works. They will handle your application just like a regular one"                    but I was assured by the call center in UK and the vfs application center for uk visa, that I can reapply in fast track.    Hear it's the entry level officers mistake of seeing my income wrong , how do I get this message to the visa officer in chennai , that it's their fault. I have even submitted 3 years tax returns, which show sufficient earning

Comment: Nean der, reapplying or not is my main question . As in refusal their is a point where it says if you reapply chances are you most likely will get refusal.

Comment: @NandaMadhavaram "unless the circumstances change".. in your case the circumstances will change since an error will cleared.. right?

Comment: @der thal, it will change, as I will have to point out their mistake. But was worried , if they would just refuse a visa just to prove them right.  And I am surprised that they could not see my tax returns and determine my earnings.

Comment: I think you should reapply. However you not only have to point out their error, you also have to clearly document the source of the monies going in and out of your account aside from your salary and the **other income**. That is very important, they are particular about funds parking and money laundering. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications

Comment: Please learn to write numbers properly in English when dealing with non-Indians. It's not 4,00,000 but 400,000. it's not 20,00,000 but 2,000,000. A comma every three zeroes. I know it's an Indian custom, but when dealing with non-Indians, please revert to the traditional way. Or Westerners can get easily confused...

Comment: @dda first pls know  if the application allowes commas or not before advising. In uk visa application it does not let you add any commas. I did add commas to explain people in this group.

Comment: New that you've posted the refusal letter, we can see that the refusal does not depend on the misreading of your income. Nowhere does the letter state that the amounts are insufficient.

Answer (score 12):

> However, they refused my visa, saying that **my monthly income** was 2,00,000 INR and the other income was 4,00,000 INR. It looks like they misread the amounts.

Where do they say that? They clearly say **per annum** on the refusal letter and that means **per year**.

We don't even know how you answered those questions, It is also possible that you answered the questions incorrectly by mistake, making the reader assume that the 4 Million (or 400K as they read) that you mention is an additional income?

What were your answers to these questions literally?

> How much do you earn from this job in a year?
>
> Do you have another income or any savings?
>
> How much money do you have in savings (in GBP)?
>
> What is the total amount of money you spend each month

I don't mean to say its you who are wrong and they can't be, but that **before you reapply** you need to be sure of what you entered and double check it and only then point out someone's mistake in the additional notes section of the application. You can just open the PDF file that i'm sure you will already have of your application and see if the mistake was first on your end.

There is no problem with a **comma** or no comma, Once the application is saved in the system it does not list any commas in the numbers so this confusion has nothing to do with digit grouping.

Do not reapply until you are sure that the mistake is only on their end and not on yours. Otherwise you will unwittingly make the same mistake on your subsequent application.

And, as noted by @MadHatter below, **you also need to explain the source of your other income**. If you focus solely on saying that there was a mistake then you will get another refusal letter saying ok so we acknowledge you make 10 times more than that but you failed to specify the source of that money and your statements don't show the origins.

Comment: +1 from me.  Note also that the refusal letter doesn't say the amount is inadequate; it says that your evidence does not add up ("*the transactions shown do not correspond to your stated combined income*").  We didn't see the evidence you provided, but you should look at it carefully yourself and *see if it proves what you claim*.

Comment: @MadHatter your point cannot be stressed enough. It should really be the first point in any answer: *the refusal does not depend on the mistake in the income amount.*  Correcting that mistake and nothing else would probably lead to another refusal.

Comment: The refusal status clearly “200 thousand rupees per annum (per year) and 400 thousand rupees per annum from other income” while OP said his income was “2 million per year plus other income for a total of 4 million per year”, so _two_ massive differences. It’s then obvious that the bank statements don’t match what they _think_ his income is and look suspicious.